# How to replace an anchor text character with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am not very experienced with JavaScript and still learning this.

In my webpage at the end of few anchor tags text there are few characters that I want to remove with JavaScript library (jQuery).
I am using this code but it's not helping me to get rid of these characters.

```
jQuery("a").each(function() {
jQuery(this).text().replace('[L]','');
});
```

I have tried to find help from other such questions but still struggling to get this done.

Can anyone guide me?

What is the issue with this code?

I will appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Comment: can you please give an anchor tag example text

Comment: Try `this.innerText = this.innerText.replace('\[L\]','');`

Comment: For example from this anchor tag text "OVERSTOCK FAQ[L]" I want to remove [L]. There are few others tags with the same issue and i want to correct all these. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comment

```js
$("a").each(function() {
  this.innerText = this.innerText.replace('\[L\]','');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">This link text [L]</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. It is working for me now. Can you tell me how these slashes are working around [L] ?

Comment: When you look at the function [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) documentation, its first parameter could be `regex` or `str`. In this particular code I have used `regex` as it replaces all matches of the searched string. In regular expression square brackets are special characters, so to define them as regular characters they need to be `escaped` with the slash. If you need more details about regular expressions, you may visit [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html)  page

Answer (score 2):

Without `each` loop. See below.

```js
$('a').text(function(index, currentText) {
  return currentText.replace('[L]', '')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Lorem ipsum [L]</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use text() property to replace

```js
var jQuery = $; 

jQuery("a").each(function() {

 jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace('[L]',''));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">OVERSTOCK FAQ[L]</a>
```

Comment: You don't need regular expression `jQuery(this).text(jQuery(this).text().replace('[L]',''));` will do.

Comment: Also, if you want to use `jQuery` instead of `$` you use `$.noConflict();`

Comment: @Dinesh Now thats my answer :p

Comment: I said this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44621605/5289704. anyways my +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
var element;
var replace;
jQuery("a").each(function() {

element = jQuery(this).text();

replace = element.replace('[L]','');

jQuery(this).text(replace);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">OVERSTOCK FAQ[L]</a>
<a href="#">OVERSTOCK FAQ[L]</a>
<a href="#">OVERSTOCK FAQ[L]</a>
```